# Pyhon - merging two list of dictionaries, only last dictionary in the second list returned

Tags: python, list, loops, dictionary

I tried doing a bit of search in SO to find a solution, but I'm still stumped. I think I'm fundamentally misunderstanding something about loops, lists and dictionaries.

I'm largely self-taught and by no means an expert, so apologies in advance if this is an incredibly stupid question.

I have various lists of dictionaries like the l1 and l2 samples in the snippet below.
My desired output is something like

```
l3 = [{'A':1, 'B':4},{'A':2,'B':5},{'A':3,'B':6}
```

However, no matter what I try I always seem to be getting only the last key-value pair from the second dictionary, i.e.

```
[{'A': 1, 'B': 6}, {'A': 2, 'B': 6}, {'A': 3, 'B': 6}]
```

This is what I've got (comments to explain what I'm thinking the code is/should be doing)

```
# First list of dictionaries

l1 = [{'A': 1},{'A': 2},{'A': 3}]
print(l1)

# Second list of dictionaries
l2 = [{'B': 4},{'B': 5},{'B': 6}]
print(l2)

# Empty list - to receive dictionaries in l1 and l2
l3 =[]
print(l3)

# Adding dictionaries from l1 into l3
for dict1 in l1:
    l3.append(dict1)
print(l3)

# Opening l3 to loop through each dictionary, using range(len()) to loop through the index positions
for i in range(len(l3)):

    # Opening l2 to loop through each dictionary
    for dict2 in l2:
        l3[i].update(dict2)
print(l3)

# Tried inverting the lists here, looping through l2 and then looping through l3 to append all dictionaries in l2
for dict2 in l2:
    for i in range(len(l3)):
        l3[i].update(dict2)
print(l3)
```

I also tried using zip() and ended up with a list of tuples of dictionaries which makes me think I'm either using that incorrectly, or it's too complex a tool for what I need here.
From what I could understand doing some research, the problem is that I keep overriding the values I have just written, I assume that's why I consistently end up with only the last value added everywhere.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick in one line of code:

```
# First list of dictionaries
l1 = [{'A': 1},{'A': 2},{'A': 3}]
print(l1)

# Second list of dictionaries
l2 = [{'B': 4},{'B': 5},{'B': 6}]
print(l2)

# add dictionaries for dictionaries in zipped list1 and list2
l3 = [dict(d1, **d2) for d1, d2 in zip(l1, l2) ]
print(l3)
```

Output:

```
[{'A': 1}, {'A': 2}, {'A': 3}]
[{'B': 4}, {'B': 5}, {'B': 6}]
[{'A': 1, 'B': 4}, {'A': 2, 'B': 5}, {'A': 3, 'B': 6}]
```

Answer (score 3):

Your code here is incorrect. For each dict in l3, you update every single dict in l2.

```
for i in range(len(l3)):

    # Opening l2 to loop through each dictionary
    for dict2 in l2:
        l3[i].update(dict2)
```

Try this:

```
for i in range(len(l3)):
    l3[i].update(l2[i])
```

Here is a better solution:
The second list dictionary value will overwrite the first one, if they have the same key.

```
result = list(map(lambda x,y:{**x, **y}, l1, l2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first problem is here:

```
# Adding dictionaries from l1 into l3
for dict1 in l1:
    l3.append(dict1)
print(l3)
```

You're copying the *references* to all the dicts in the first list. They are the same as in your first list. That means, editing a dict (like with a call to `update()`) will affect **both** lists.

```
# Opening l3 to loop through each dictionary, using range(len()) to loop through the index positions
for i in range(len(l3)):

    # Opening l2 to loop through each dictionary
    for dict2 in l2:
        l3[i].update(dict2)
print(l3)

# Tried inverting the lists here, looping through l2 and then looping through l3 to append all dictionaries in l2
for dict2 in l2:
    for i in range(len(l3)):
        l3[i].update(dict2)
print(l3)
```

Here you're looping over the dicts twice. `l3` is a copy of `l1`, and for each item in that list, you update it with data from *each* of the items in `l2`. Dicts must have unique keys so each time you update keys `a` and `b`, it overwrites the previous values.

Then you basically do the same thing but in different order.

What you want to do it iterate the dicts in each list at the same time, and create new dicts from the data in each. Dicts at each location in the list have unique keys so there won't be any overwriting.

```
l3 = [{**d1, **d2} for d1, d2 in zip(l1, l2)]
```

`zip()` is the right function to use here. It takes one item from each list and hands them to you as a pair. Item at position `i` in one list and the other list.

```
>>> print(list(zip(l1, l2)))
[({'A': 1}, {'B': 4}), ({'A': 2}, {'B': 5}), ({'A': 3}, {'B': 6})]
```

So once you have that, create a new dict from the source dicts. As you know `{}` is syntax for a new dict, and doing `**` on a variable means extracting items (key/value pairs) and inserting them into the new dict.

Another, less pythonic, but perhaps easier for a newbie way to write it would be like this:

```
l3 = []

for d1, d2 in zip(l1, l2):
  d3 = {}
  d3.update(d1)
  d3.update(d2)
  l3.append(d3)
```

I hope you can appreciate the brevity of the first solution.

Comment: Thanks - I appreciate the explanation as well!